# Prevent cycle counting the first two iteration

Tags: django, django-templates

Im trying to display the first two objects of a forloop in a special way. And the rest should be grouped in three.

Like this:

```
<div class="row">
    Object 1

    Object 2 - Object slug
</div><!--/end first row with 2 objects-->


<div class="row">
    Object 3

    Object 4

    Object 5
</div><!--/end row with 3 objects-->

<div class="row">
    Object 6

    Object 7

    Object 8
</div><!--/end row with 3 objects-->
```

Here is my template code:

```
{% for object in object_list %}

    {% if forloop.first %}
        <div class="row">

            {{object.name}}

    {% elif forloop.counter == 2 %}

            {{object.name}} - {{object.slug}}

        </div><!--/end first row with 2 objects-->

    {% else %}

    {% cycle '<div class="row">' '' '' %}

            {{object.name}} - {{object.slug}}


    {% cycle '' '' '</div><!--/end row with 3 objects-->' %}


    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

This code does not work, because the cycle tag counts first and second. How could I fix this?

Comment: Have you considered using a plugin? https://pythonhosted.org/django-templateaddons/template_tags/counter.html

Comment: Your template works the way you want when I run it locally, is this your real code or a dummied up example?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you shouldn't do that in template. You should create such a object in view and then iterate.

For example, now you have `object` which is an array:

```
object = ['object1', 'object2', 'object3', 'object4' , 'object5', 'object6', '...']
```

And my idea is to make this object look like this:

```
object = (['object1', 'object2'], ['object3', 'object4' , 'object5'], [...])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code Im using now. And it seem to work. On the first page, the two first articles are grouped together, and the rest is grouped by three. On other pages, all the articles are grouped by three.

```
{% for object in object_list %}


    {% if forloop.first and page_number == 1 %}
        <div class="row">

            <div class="news-article">
            {{ object.title }}
            </div>


    {% elif forloop.counter == 2 and page_number == 1 %}

            <div class="news-article">
            {{ object.title }}
            </div>


        </div><!-- /first row-->


    {% else %}


        {% cycle '<div class="row">' '' '' %}

            <div class="news-article">
            {{ object.title }}
            </div>


    {% endif %}

    {% if page_number == 1 %}
        {% if not forloop.counter == 1 and not forloop.counter == 2  %}
            {% cycle '' '' '</div><!--/row-->' %}
        {% endif %}

    {% else %}
        {% cycle '' '' '</div><!--/row-->' %}
    {% endif %}


    {% if not forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" and forloop.last %}
        </div><!--row.last-->
    {% endif %}


{% endfor %}
```